# How do you Resize a Photo Pulled from a Website in a Tkinter Window

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

I am trying to have a tkinter window that shows several photos that can be selected. I keep coming across an error "PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize", but all of the guides/forums that I've looked up have the same code. How do you resize an image that you pulled from a website?

```
url="https://cdn.fileviewerplus.com/img/icon/256/cr2-52.png"
u=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
raw_data=u.read()
u.close()
b64_data = base64.encodestring(raw_data)
photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=b64_data)
image=photo.resize((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are trying to use methods built in pillow. You can import the file as a pillow image file and then use `resize`. Then use it in your tkinter environment.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

url = 'https://cdn.fileviewerplus.com/img/icon/256/cr2-52.png'
u = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
img = Image.open(u)
img = img.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

Also, as @acw1668 caught, you should use `ImageTk` from pillow here.

Comment: `ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)` from PIL should be used instead of `tk.PhotoImage(img)`.